# What's the disadvantage of creating prototype methods inside the object?

Tags: javascript

I have seen people take two approaches when they create javascript objects, they sometimes define the prototype functions outside the main object and sometimes they do it inside. Defining the prototype functions inside the object has the advantage of using private variables and functions, what's the advantage of defining it outside?

```
function something (params) {
  this.name = params.name;
  this.color = params.color;
  _someprivatefunction = function () {};
  something.prototype.publicFunction = function () {_someprivatefunction() };
}
```

As opposed to:

```
function something (params) {
  this.name = params.name;
  this.color = params.color;
  _someprivatefunction = function () {};
}

something.prototype.publicFunction = function () {//can't call the private function here };
```

EDIT: as suggested in the comments down below, this is a third option (but the problem with this is now the private function cant access any of the private variables inside the constructor.)

```
(function () {
  function something (params) {
    this.name = params.name;
    this.color = params.color;
   }

   _someprivatefunction = function () {};

   something.prototype.publicFunction = function () {_someprivatefunction() };
 }());
```

Comment: That first one looks just plain weird to me. It's going to re-define the function at the prototype level each time you create a new instance. That function will have access to closure variables for the last-created instance only (no matter what instance you invoke it through.

Am I wrong about this in some way?

Comment: @SteveJorgensen yes, first option is probably written by someone who doesn't know what prototype is and re defining it every instance creation is pointless. jsfriends solution (3rd) is better if you need functions that access instance specific private variables (privileged functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I think you know, your two code blocks don't offer the same functionality.  The first option allows you to call `_someprivatefunction()` or other private constructor variables and your second does not.  So, first you have to decide if that's a requirement or not.  Your two options do not offer equivalent functionality.

If you do want access to the private function, then a third option is as follows:

```
function something (params) {
    // initialize data members
    this.name = params.name;
    this.color = params.color;

    // initialize private members
    var aPrivateInstanceVar = 4;

    // define private function
    _someprivatefunction = function () { console.log(aPrivateInstanceVar);};

    // define public method with access to private members and functions
    this.publicFunction = function () {_someprivatefunction() };
}
```

This new option will technically work the same as your first option.  But (and this might just be my opinion), it feels cleaner.  It's assigning a property dynamically to the object at creation time which is a much more common thing to do (just like assigning to `this.name` and `this.color`) than assigning something to the prototype at object creation time.

Also, if I came across some uncommented code someone else wrote that has your first construction in it, my first thought would be: "gee, why isn't this assignment to the prototype done once outside the constructor" and I might even attempt to "fix" it without realizing that it needed to be there.  But, if I came across the structure I'm proposing, it would like like a perfectly common design pattern and I would not be tempted to "fix" the code (accidentally breaking it in the process).

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that a disadvantage to the first approach is that you are running the prototype assignment every time you instantiate a new object. Seems like it would defeat the purpose of using the prototype since it does work on the object for every instance created.

Comment: You're missing that the code in the prototype in the first block is calling a private function that is only available in the constructor.  That simply can't be done outside the constructor.

Comment: I still think option two is more desirable. It doesn't seem like a good design choice to call the prototype in the constructor function. To achieve the same behavior I would recommend that you wrap it in a self executing closure but move the private function out of the constructor so that it's still a private function to the outside, but available internally to the prototype call.

Comment: The second construction doesn't offer equivalent functionality as the first construction because only the first construction offers access to other per-instance private variables in the constructor.  If the choice is only between 1 and 2, the choice needs to be made based on which functionality is needed.  I offered a third choice in my answer that offers the same access to private variables in the constructor, but doesn't use the prototype in that way (which I agree with you, seems odd and out of place).